# Convert string ( JAN 2014) to date in SSIS 2005

Tags: sql, ssis

The data from source has string data type (JAN-2014) I want valid date and convert string to date. How can I do this in SSIS 2005?

Example : Jan-2014.

I want convert this date to 201401 type. Can anyone explain how I can go about this..

Comment: Do you have many strings with this date format? I assume this would not be an easy task as your string date format cannot be easily turned into date with just data conversation.

Comment: The string date type will be like 'mmm'(first 3 letters of month) format. Could you please guide me to go right track?

Comment: Do you know how to work with derived columns and conditional split? I'd probably solve this problem with these transformations.

Comment: You could do this in a Script Transformation. How do you plan to store the output - as a DateTime type or Varchar type?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SUBSTRING(Col,FINDSTRING(Col,"-",1) + 1,4) + 
RIGHT("0" + 
          (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",
                                 (DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING(Col,1,4) +
                                 SUBSTRING(Col,FINDSTRING(Col,"-",1) +
                                           1,4)
                                           )),2)
```

The above expression will convert `Jan-2014` to `201401` string format.